# Offline login with encrypted local database ? Security Issues

Tags: security, encryption, credentials, cracking, offline-mode

The first time, the user will log in in his account and I will check if credentials are correct in the Online Database. Then I will store all his data (including device id) in a local database in order to be able to login in offline mode.

I want to know if it's worth to include a offline mode in my application or it carries high security risks allowing crackers to crack my app.

If so, what is the securest way to do this ?

Comment: This question is too broad, and will probably be closed.  You need to be more specific (and probably want to ask on a security-specific stackexchange site, like http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Alright I will do it if closed. Thanks for the advice.